# Transfer a file to a different folder - bash

Tags: bash, file, text

In bash, I am creating a text file as follows:

```
echo " My text file" > new.txt
```

My current folder is scripts_new .

How can I transfer this file `new.txt` to another folder (`scripts_old`), i.e. a folder different from my present folder which I am working in (`scripts_new`) in which it is automatically put?

Comment: Try `echo " My text file" > ../scripts_old/new.txt`

Comment: Or try `mv new.txt ../scripts_old/` after your file is created.

Comment: Both the commands work, Thanks !

Comment: The way to mark a problem as solved is to accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to it. Please don't edit the word "SOLVED" into your title.

Comment: @KeithThompson that wasn't him sadly.. edit records show it was 'anubhava'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `mv` command something like this:

```
mv new.txt ../scripts_old
```

Answer (score 1):

To preface, in Linux your current working directory is referenced by `.` and the directory 'up' in the directory tree is `..`.

So let's say you have two directories:

`/home/ubuntu/scripts_old/`

and

`/home/ubuntu/scripts_new/`

To move something (new.txt) from one to the other, you would just use:

`mv /home/ubuntu/scripts_old/new.txt /home/ubuntu/scripts_new/`

Or if you are currently in `/home/ubuntu/scripts_new` (current location can be determined by `pwd`), you can do the same with:

`mv new.txt ../scripts_old/`